# $|f(x)| \leq |g(x)|$ implies $f$ is differentiable at $0$?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

I'm trying to tackle a question at the moment.

For some function $f$ such that $|f(x)|\leq|g(x)|$, we have that $f(x)$ is differentiable at $0$ if $g$ satisfies what property?

From the understanding I have developed so far, this is a sort of squeeze theorem problem involving the first principle definition of differentiability;

$\lim\limits_{h\to0} \frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}$ needs to be bounded above and below by something in order to show that it exists. For example if we choose $g(x)=x^2$ then we can say that, since $|f(x)|\leq x^2$,
\begin{align*}
-h^2 &\leq f(h) \leq h^2 \\
\implies -h &\leq \frac{f(h)}{h} \leq h, \\
\end{align*}
and we can say

$$\lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h} = \lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(h)}{h},$$ 
and this limit exists (from previously).

However I am having a hard time generalising this concept. Just looking for a few tips. Thanks!

Comment: This is such an open ended question. Do you know nothing else about $g$ or $f$? Who's to say they are continuous, even?

Comment: No, that's the point - I have to figure out which conditions g needs to satisfy for this to be true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $f,g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}.$

If $g$ is differentiable at a fixed $x$ and both $g(x) = g'(x) =0$ then having $|f| \leqslant |g|$ will imply differentiability of $f$ at this $x$ as well. In particular $f'(x) = 0$.

You basically already proved this. Note that $|f(x)| \leqslant |g(x)| = 0 \Longrightarrow f(x) = 0$, whence

\begin{align*} \left\lvert \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} - 0 \right\rvert &= \frac{|f(x+h)|}{|h|}   \\[10pt] &\leqslant \frac{|g(x+h)|}{|h|} \\[10pt] &= \left\lvert \frac{g(x+h) -g(x)}{h} -
 g'(x) \right\rvert \xrightarrow{h \to 0} 0. \end{align*}

I don't think too much can be said if $g(x),g'(x)$ aren't both zero. For example, the constant function $g \equiv 1$ is infinitely differentiable on the entire real line ($g'(x) = 0$ everywhere as well), but although the map
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 0, & x \in \mathbb{Q} \\ 1,& x \notin \mathbb{Q} \end{cases}$$
satisfies, $|f| \leqslant |g|$, it is not true that $f$ is differentiable anywhere. It is not even continuous anywhere.

Comment: You can also have $g(x)=x$ and $$f(x)=\begin{cases}0,&x\in\mathbb Q\\x,&x\notin \mathbb Q.\end{cases}$$ This gives a $g(x)$ with $g(0)=0$, and you even have $f$ continuous at $0$.

Comment: True, so having $|f| \leqslant |g|$, infinite differentiability of $g$ everywhere, and continuity of $f$ at a fixed $x$ still does not imply differentiability of $f$ at said $x$.

Comment: You can also come up with examples where $f$ is continuous everywhere, like $f(x)=x\sin \frac{1}{x}, f(0)=0$, then $f'(0)$ doesn't exist but $|f(x)|\leq |x|$.